# Unable to limit the categories in REST response, even when a location is provide in the 'in' or 'at' clause [HERE Maps Places API]

Tags: javascript, here-api, here-maps-rest

The Place Categories REST Entrypoint of HERE PLACES API is returning all categories defined in API rather than returning categories present specific to a location. I'm trying to execute a rest call as follows.

https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/categories/places?in=52.521,13.3807;r=777

with appropriate app_id and app_code. 
The REST call is returning all categories.

Also, when i'm trying to execute the call on 55.7006,18.2147;r=85741 (which is a sea area). All categories are shown.

Please help resolving the issue.

Regards,
Akash

Answer (score 0):

We are currently working on this. Meanwhile we try to fix it you can use our other apis to get the category information. If you are trying to get places nearby a given location then use Discover Here. Find more information in developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics/explore-nearby-places.html

```
https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/here?at=52.531%2C13.3848&Accept-Language=en-US%2Cen%3Bq%3D0.5
```

Comment: No, I'm trying to list all places categories, specific to a location.
I'm following this: https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics_api/resource-place-categories.html

Comment: Updated the answer